# How to create a 2nd app from a 2nd target in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

So I created a simple project, which I can test as an iPhone app. Now I'd like to make a slight variation of it, with an iAd. I was able to duplicate the target and test to the iPhone, by managing schemes (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html).

The issue is that no matter what scheme I test, I overwrite the other app. I'd like to be able to have two apps

- AppName
- AppName (Free)

living at the same time on my phone.

I want to avoid duplicating source files, because only the storyboard and the view controller are different, they both use the same images and model otherwise.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: If the identifiers for the apps are different, you **should** be OK.  (Look at the top text field of the summary tab for each target.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the bundle identifier in the new target you just created? So your full version would have bundle identifier: **"com.yourcompany.AppName"** and your lite version will have a bundle identifier of: **"com.youcompany.AppNameLite"**

Comment: LonelyDeveloper and Philip, thanks. I tried again and somehow it worked now. I have two apps, I needed no additional change (since I had followed what you suggested).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently on my Mac partition so sorry if I'm a bit off.
I would add a new configuration for your app. Call it something like "Release Free". Add a gcc preprocessor symbol "FREE" to this configuration.
Then everywhere you initialize and instantiate your iads put the code within some "#if" statements.

Something like this.

```
#if FREE
    // Init iAds
#endif
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this, so I have separate view controllers.